# Why is this javascript function returning two different values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Currently working on a function with this requirements:

Given an array nums and a value val, remove all instances of that value in-place and return the array.
Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory. The order of elements can be changed.

Im encountering a weird issue in which the function returns two different values at the same time, and I'm baffled about why this thing happens. Here's the code:

```js
var removeElement = function(nums, val) {
  let left = 0;
  let right = nums.length - 1;
  
  while(left < right || left === nums.length - 1) {
    if(nums[left] !== val && nums[right] !== val) {
      left++;
    } else if(nums[left] === val && nums[right] === val) {
      right--;
      nums.length--;
    } else {
      if(nums[right] === val) {
        left++;
        right--;
        nums.length--;
      } else if(nums[left] === val){
        var tempLeft = nums[left];
        nums[left] = nums[right];
        nums[right] = tempLeft;
        nums.length--;
        right--;
        left++;
      }
    }
  }
  return nums;
};

console.log(removeElement([0,1,2,2,3,0,4,2], 2));
```

**Expected output**

```
[0,1,3,0,4] // in no particular order
```

**Current output**

```
[0,1,4,0,3]
[0,1,6,5]
```

Comment: It clearly returns `[0, 1, 4, 0, 3]` - There must be some other code producing `[0,1,6,5]`

Comment: Running the function only returns a single array. You can run the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

You can check right here and i checked on different playgrounds - it returns only [0,1,4,0,3].

Provide more details on how you run it, please.

Comment: I was running it in jsbin, ill try elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

[image]

and here's the result from jsbin